# ng-pluralize with yml html translation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yaml, angularjs-ng-pluralize

I'm trying to use ng-pluralize to conditionally display HTML based on yml translations. Unfortunately, the HTML is ignored by ng-pluralize and displayed as a string literal with the count interpolated. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to?

HAML

```
%span(ng-if="user.streak_count" ng-pluralize 
count="user.streak_count" when="{'1': #{t('.one_streak_html')},
'other': #{t('.streak_html')} }")
```

YML

```
streak_html: "'<b>{}</b> days in a row'"
one_streak_html: "'<b>{}</b> day in a row'"
```

Displayed

```
<b>2</b> days in a row
```

Comment: Did you solve it? We are running into a similar issue here.

Comment: @Robert I can't seem to figure out where, but I remember reading about an open issue in the repo saying that it wasn't currently supported. Ended up with something more ugly unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little bit late, but in case anyone still has some problem with this one, I created directives that can solve this problem. It can be found [here](https://github.com/christianesperar/ng-pluralize-html)

You can see it in action [here](https://rawgit.com/christianesperar/ng-pluralize-html/master/example/github.html)